# WebSocket connection with PHP

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

I want to connect to webSocket server with PHP, but for some reason do not succeed, but a displays message is "Connected".

PHP:

```
$host="i[..].herokuapp.com" ;  
$port=443;  
$timeout=30;  
$sk=fsockopen($host,$port,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout) ;  
echo $errstr;  
if (!is_resource($sk)) {  
 exit("connection fail: ".$errnum." ".$errstr) ;  
} else {  
 echo "Connected";  
fwrite($sk, '{""mi":1,"ertek":"a"}') or die('Error:' . $errno . ':' . $errstr);  
fclose($sk);  
 }
```

And Nodejs Websocket server:

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;  
var http = require("http");  
var express = require("express");  
var app = express();  
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;  

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));  

var server = http.createServer(app);  
server.listen(port);  

var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
wss.on("connection", function(ws) {  
[...]  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This working:

```
 public function __construct() { }

 public function __destruct()
 {
 $this->disconnect();
 }
 public function sendData($data, $type = 'text', $masked = true, $return = false)
 {
 if(!$this->_connected)
 {
 //echo "Not connected";
 return false;
 }
 if( !is_string($data)) {
 //echo "Not a string data was given.";
 return false;
 }
 if (strlen($data) == 0)
 {
 return false;
 }
 $res = fwrite($this->_Socket, $this->_hybi10Encode($data, $type, $masked));
 if($res === 0 || $res === false)
 {
 return false;
 }
 $buffer = ' ';
if($return){
 while(!empty($buffer))
 {
 $buffer = fread($this->_Socket, 512);// drop?
 }

 return $buffer;
}else{
 return true;
}
 }
 public function connect($host, $port = 80, $path = 'into.hu', $origin = true)
 {
 $this->_host = $host;
 $this->_port = $port;
 $this->_path = $path;
 $this->_origin = $origin;

 $key = base64_encode($this->_generateRandomString(16, false, true));
 $header = "GET ws://".$host . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
 $header.= "Host: ".$host.":".$port."\r\n";
 $header.= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
 $header.= "Pragma: no-cache\r\n";
 $header.= "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n";
 $header.= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
 $header.= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
 $header.= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36\r\n";
 $header.= "Accept-Language: hu,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-AU;q=0.4\r\n";
 $header.= "Sec-WebSocket-Key: " . $key . "\r\n";
 if($origin !== false)
 {
 $header.= "Origin: ".$path."\r\n";
 $header.= "Sec-WebSocket-Origin: " . $origin . "\r\n";
 }
 $header.= "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n\r\n";

 $this->_Socket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
 //socket_set_timeout($this->_Socket, 0, 10000);
 fwrite($this->_Socket, $header);
 $response = fread($this->_Socket, 200);
if(!empty($response)){
$this->_connected = true;
}

/*
 preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Accept:\s(.*)$#mU', $response, $matches);

 if ($matches) {
 $keyAccept = trim($matches[1]);
 $expectedResonse = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($key . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
 $this->_connected = ($keyAccept === $expectedResonse) ? true : false;
 }
*/
 return $this->_connected;
 }

 public function checkConnection()
 {
 $this->_connected = false;

 // send ping:
 $data = 'ping?';
 @fwrite($this->_Socket, $this->_hybi10Encode($data, 'ping', true));
 $response = @fread($this->_Socket, 300);
 if(empty($response))
 {
 return false;
 }
 $response = $this->_hybi10Decode($response);
 if(!is_array($response))
 {
 return false;
 }
 if(!isset($response['type']) || $response['type'] !== 'pong')
 {
 return false;
 }
 $this->_connected = true;
 return true;
 }
 public function disconnect()
 {
 $this->_connected = false;
 is_resource($this->_Socket) and fclose($this->_Socket);
 }

 public function reconnect()
 {
 sleep(2);
 $this->_connected = false;
 fclose($this->_Socket);
 $this->connect($this->_host, $this->_port, $this->_path, $this->_origin);
 }
 private function _generateRandomString($length = 10, $addSpaces = true, $addNumbers = true)
 {
 $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"§$%&/()=[]{}';
 $useChars = array();
 // select some random chars:
 for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
 {
 $useChars[] = $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
 }
 // add spaces and numbers:
 if($addSpaces === true)
 {
 array_push($useChars, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');
 }
 if($addNumbers === true)
 {
 array_push($useChars, rand(0,9), rand(0,9), rand(0,9));
 }
 shuffle($useChars);
 $randomString = trim(implode('', $useChars));
 $randomString = substr($randomString, 0, $length);
 return $randomString;
 }

 private function _hybi10Encode($payload, $type = 'text', $masked = true)
 {
 $frameHead = array();
 $frame = '';
 $payloadLength = strlen($payload);

 switch($type)
 {
 case 'text':
 // first byte indicates FIN, Text-Frame (10000001):
 $frameHead[0] = 129;
 break;

 case 'close':
 // first byte indicates FIN, Close Frame(10001000):
 $frameHead[0] = 136;
 break;

 case 'ping':
 // first byte indicates FIN, Ping frame (10001001):
 $frameHead[0] = 137;
 break;

 case 'pong':
 // first byte indicates FIN, Pong frame (10001010):
 $frameHead[0] = 138;
 break;
 }

 // set mask and payload length (using 1, 3 or 9 bytes)
 if($payloadLength > 65535)
 {
 $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%064b', $payloadLength), 8);
 $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 255 : 127;
 for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++)
 {
 $frameHead[$i+2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[$i]);
 }
 // most significant bit MUST be 0 (close connection if frame too big)
 if($frameHead[2] > 127)
 {
 $this->close(1004);
 return false;
 }
 }
 elseif($payloadLength > 125)
 {
 $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $payloadLength), 8);
 $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 254 : 126;
 $frameHead[2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[0]);
 $frameHead[3] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[1]);
 }
 else
 {
 $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
 }
 // convert frame-head to string:
 foreach(array_keys($frameHead) as $i)
 {
 $frameHead[$i] = chr($frameHead[$i]);
 }
 if($masked === true)
 {
 // generate a random mask:
 $mask = array();
 for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
 {
 $mask[$i] = chr(rand(0, 255));
 }

 $frameHead = array_merge($frameHead, $mask);
 }
 $frame = implode('', $frameHead);
 // append payload to frame:
 $framePayload = array();
 for($i = 0; $i < $payloadLength; $i++)
 {
 $frame .= ($masked === true) ? $payload[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4] : $payload[$i];
 }
 return $frame;
 }

 private function _hybi10Decode($data)
 {
 $payloadLength = '';
 $mask = '';
 $unmaskedPayload = '';
 $decodedData = array();

 // estimate frame type:
 $firstByteBinary = sprintf('%08b', ord($data[0]));
 $secondByteBinary = sprintf('%08b', ord($data[1]));
 $opcode = bindec(substr($firstByteBinary, 4, 4));
 $isMasked = ($secondByteBinary[0] == '1') ? true : false;
 $payloadLength = ord($data[1]) & 127;

 switch($opcode)
 {
 // text frame:
 case 1:
 $decodedData['type'] = 'text';
 break;

 case 2:
 $decodedData['type'] = 'binary';
 break;

 // connection close frame:
 case 8:
 $decodedData['type'] = 'close';
 break;

 // ping frame:
 case 9:
 $decodedData['type'] = 'ping';
 break;

 // pong frame:
 case 10:
 $decodedData['type'] = 'pong';
 break;

 default:
 return false;
 break;
 }

 if($payloadLength === 126)
 {
 $mask = substr($data, 4, 4);
 $payloadOffset = 8;
 $dataLength = bindec(sprintf('%08b', ord($data[2])) . sprintf('%08b', ord($data[3]))) + $payloadOffset;
 }
 elseif($payloadLength === 127)
 {
 $mask = substr($data, 10, 4);
 $payloadOffset = 14;
 $tmp = '';
 for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++)
 {
 $tmp .= sprintf('%08b', ord($data[$i+2]));
 }
 $dataLength = bindec($tmp) + $payloadOffset;
 unset($tmp);
 }
 else
 {
 $mask = substr($data, 2, 4);
 $payloadOffset = 6;
 $dataLength = $payloadLength + $payloadOffset;
 }

 if($isMasked === true)
 {
 for($i = $payloadOffset; $i < $dataLength; $i++)
 {
 $j = $i - $payloadOffset;
 if(isset($data[$i]))
 {
 $unmaskedPayload .= $data[$i] ^ $mask[$j % 4];
 }
 }
 $decodedData['payload'] = $unmaskedPayload;
 }
 else
 {
 $payloadOffset = $payloadOffset - 4;
 $decodedData['payload'] = substr($data, $payloadOffset);
 }

 return $decodedData;
 }
}

$WebSocketClient = new WebsocketClient();
$WebSocketClient->connect('i[..].herokuapp.com',80,'valami.hu');
//$WebSocketClient->reconnect();
$WebSocketClient->sendData('üzenet küldés');
unset($WebSocketClient);
?>
```